# How to space horizontally a mat-checkbox and it's label?

Tags: angular, material-design

**[SOLVED] EDIT** 
I just added my own label instead of the material design included one with the checkbox.

---

Some designers handed me a mockup designed with the Adobe Xd Material Design tool. My problem is: how to space the material design checkbox itself from it's label horizontally?

I've tried using an ::ng-deep on the `mat-checkbox-layout` (which is on inline-flex display mode btw) with `justify-content: space between`.

Here is an image of [the mat-checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/897SU.jpg) I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: can you please share your code using stackblitz ?

Comment: I just figured out how to solve my problem! I just put my own label outside of the checkbox itself.

```<label>{{mode.name}}</label>
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" [labelPosition]="labelPosition">
</mat-checkbox>```